# Access a variable defined in Jenkinsfiles in Shell Script within Jenkinsfile

Tags: unix, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am defining a shell script in one of the stages in my Jenkinsfile. How can I access a variable that I define in my Jenkinsfile with the shell script?

In below scenario , I am writing the value of the shell variable to a file and reading into a groovy variable. Is there a way to pass data from shell to groovy without writing it to file system?

```
unstash 'sources'

                    sh'''
                      source venv/bin/activate
                      export AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::<accountid>:role/<role name>
                      layer_arn="$(awssume aws lambda list-layer-versions --layer-name dependencies --region us-east-1 --query \"LayerVersions[0].LayerVersionArn\" | tr -d '\"')"
                      echo $layer_arn > layer_arn
                    '''
                    layer_arn = readFile('layer_arn').trim()
```

Comment: You can use an environment variable.

Comment: Can you give some code snippet?

Comment: Hi @Tuan , added some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can can shell command line, providing variable value.

```
   sh "some stuff $my_var"
```

- You can defined environment variable and use it within your shell

```
withEnv(["MY_VAR=${my_var}") {
   sh 'some stuff'
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks @Grunnpi , I have updated the issue that I am having in my question.

Comment: ```sh()``` function can echo a return value you can set in a JenkinsFile variable. ie : ```MY_FOO = sh (script: "echo bar", returnStdout: true)```

Comment: How can I do multiple lines with sh function?

Comment: For complex output, I think you should then rely on intermediate file .propertie or .yaml, and then read using ```readYaml()``` to access through object.

Comment: In the code snippet I my post , im writing to file system and reading the file using groovy. Is that the way to do it ?

Comment: Your way will set one value to one file, that's okay. You could also add and happens multiple value to one file to access all in one object, but that doesn't change so much you goal/implementation.